# Visual Studio remove license

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, license-key

I want to remove the license from Visual Studio (2012/2013) from a computer, that I am no longer use, but I am not allowed to format or reinstall the operating system.

I have read some answers about how to change the license by editing the register, I want to know if it is possible to remove the licenses without changing the register and not leaving the visual studio installation corrupted.

Thanks

Comment: Other than editing the registry, I suppose the only other way is to remove Visual Studio (and optionally reinstall the trial version). You can use `vs_setup /uninstall /force` from the installation media (or the web installer) to completely remove the installed version without having to format the computer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to uninstall it and remove license from registry as well [chance license](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810695/1257607)

Comment: I did both to be completely sure