# How to change Visual Studio 2015 License Key?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am no longer allowed to use my current license of Visual Studio 2015 pro and need to change it for a new one. Is there any simple way to change license key?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, do you mean activate VS or just where to put your new key? http://screencast.com/t/RYQat6Nv0bC

Comment: I meant re-activation of existing installation using new key. There is no option in the screen (or subscreen after "Register product" is clicked) you provided, only message, that installation is already activated.
To rephrase my question: I want to remove currently existing license, so that I am able to apply new one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anyway, I found working solution under VS2012 thread, so this is just a repost from [How to change Visual Studio 2012,2013 or 2015 License Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465361/how-to-change-visual-studio-2012-license-key)

For those who will need to remove product key from Visual Studio 2015:

- remove registry key HKCR\Licenses\4D8CFBCB-2F6A-4AD2-BABF-10E28F6F2C8F
- repair Visual Studio installation

Comment: Main concern is, did that solution work out for you?

Comment: Good to know. I've also just recently gotten a Pro license, and was afraid of situations down the road.