# Visual Studio 2015 Community Claims it is Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I had Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise installed, the trial period expired so I uninstalled it (which took a long time of reinstalling, force remove components etc as it wasn't listed in programs and features).

I've now installed Community, it shows as community in Programs and Features, but it starts up claiming to be Enterprise and with only 30 days on the clock.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32482322/639771

I tried following the instructions in the above answer, which resolved the problem of community starting with an expired Enterprise license, but all it's done is reset the clock; I want community to recognise that it's community and that it doesn't need a license!

I uninstalled with the '/force' option to be sure, and I even removed the entries from under the wow6432node in the registry.

How do I get it to recognise that it's community edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try removing Visual Studio with "/force" parameter? Check [this website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/) for more information about how to.

Comment: I did! I even went into the registry and deleted its entries from the wow6432node

Answer (score 0):

Goto VS community ->File->Account Settings->Regsiter product->Sign in with your outlook.com address or Microsoft live account

VS community get activated.

Regards,
Vinoth.