# how to get visiual studio 2015 orignal license key from windows registry

Tags: windows, visual-studio, registry

I have windows registry path which contain license key in binary form.
[image]

path:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\41717607-F34E-432C-A138-A3CFD7E25CDA\09260
```

above path return data of license key which is in binary data

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\41717607-F34E-432C-A138-A3CFD7E25CDA\09260]
@=hex:01,00,00,00,d0,8c,9d,df,01,15,d1,11,8c,7a,00,c0,4f,c2,97,eb,01,00,00,00,\
  1b,e0,d7,59,42,00,f3,4a,8e,03,33,0a,fc,4e,81,3c,04,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,\
  00,10,66,00,00,00,01,00,00,20,00,00,00,1f,f4,27,ee,1d,dc,70,c8,d1,d8,36,61,\
  4d,09,ab,c4,8f,52,00,cb,32,73,b1,98,8e,9f,c6,6e,dc,1a,e8,24,00,00,00,00,0e,\
  80,00,00,00,02,00,00,20,00,00,00,4e,f5,2c,75,9e,f2,d1,90,49,7d,99,0b,06,2a,\
  a8,7e,3d,33,f2,90,c6,c1,d3,f9,d0,8c,ab,32,49,5f,01,8f,f0,00,00,00,cf,99,9e,\
  02,7f,2e,18,64,d9,9e,ae,7e,b7,0e,c5,d8,bf,70,fb,22,8c,5f,35,08,f9,ff,0f,62,\
  e8,bc,c7,3b,74,ce,f5,db,ab,6f,23,ee,5e,37,52,43,ba,3b,fa,2f,08,5a,65,0f,05,\
  05,ce,c0,a9,83,7d,da,72,14,fe,23,7e,01,78,2b,3e,db,ab,fe,f5,27,84,cc,3f,23,\
  61,bf,97,d2,b9,6c,e2,66,30,4a,f8,f4,88,68,da,d0,92,cd,09,5e,31,9f,f4,84,74,\
  ab,60,f7,d4,d1,02,08,0c,e3,ba,e4,2d,e4,70,72,2f,9f,48,bc,6b,22,3c,5b,05,00,\
  2c,e5,5a,df,75,d8,2b,42,d6,1c,53,d6,b7,5f,e1,66,f5,d2,03,af,4c,db,05,19,a8,\
  7e,ed,e7,c0,a2,92,97,54,5d,39,91,f4,3d,a2,4c,0e,bd,fb,59,9c,43,50,d5,8d,ee,\
  31,ee,99,8e,05,2d,24,0c,ab,ab,e3,6d,ac,08,4b,6f,78,60,83,76,6a,4d,10,ad,bd,\
  fd,f1,0f,6a,91,9e,c1,c5,e3,d5,68,64,45,df,db,df,92,e8,b0,44,66,46,fb,ec,a8,\
  31,65,ae,6d,62,49,ec,fd,8d,bb,e7,02,40,00,00,00,00,6f,5d,e0,f3,05,72,7b,c8,\
  d5,d1,22,85,84,ef,41,22,24,f3,fb,18,49,c3,ed,30,e4,1e,20,5b,2d,e8,d3,cb,b0,\
  c6,f3,30,10,69,20,69,49,d3,0d,91,ec,55,37,47,ca,23,e6,ab,a1,ab,a3,79,25,78,\
  fa,d3,23,03,2e
```

Now i need to convert binary data to text and
my text is someting like `HM6NR-*****-DFW2Y-*****-*****`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34248406/9041875

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Visual Studio 2012,2013 or 2015 License Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465361/how-to-change-visual-studio-2012-2013-or-2015-license-key)

Comment: @IInspectable no, i know where is my license key located but it is in encrepted form, i need algo to convert encrpted data to text.

Comment: Answers to the duplicate explain how to decrypt the key.

Comment: @IInspectable, most of answer are telling i can remove or modify, i m creating product which get license info.for that i need some native code or some algo or library to convert. someting like https://superuser.com/questions/784578/find-key-of-installed-and-activated-instance-adobe-acrobat-professional-without. every software has different way to decode software license key. i need for visual studio.

Comment: I highly doubt that this code is publicly available. The key is stored in an encryped (maybe even hashed) form just for the reason that it cannot be copied.

Comment: The **first** comment here links to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34248406/1889329). Which part of your question does this answer not address?